dApp simulate transaction
I have a script which basically does an dapp interaction via the dApp sdk.
now the script works, no problem at all, however im trying to simulate the transaction now, (so basically not sending it) and for some reason the simulate transaction is deprecated? does anyone have idea if there's a way to simulate a transaction which involves interacting with the path oracle? then checking it's result
(for more context I pass the instruction via code and send it raw)

Could you share the error you're getting and the code snippet for this.

The simulateTransaction method isn't deprecated or going to be.
You can read more about it here in the transition guide from Anza https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/wiki/Agave-v2.0-Transition-Guide.

hi sorry I am new to the website and forgot to recheck, I sorted the problem and thank you very much it worked I was just handling the results wrongly
